# BeautifulSoup Decode error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse html files generated by Evernote using Beautiful Soup. The code is:

```
html = open('D:/page.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

It gives following error:

`File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 24274: character maps to <undefined>`

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pass *an encoded byte string*, or even a file object (opened in binary mode) to BeautifulSoup instead; it'll handle the decoding:

```
with open('D:/page.html', 'rb') as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

BeautifulSoup looks for HTML metadata in the document itself (such as a [`<meta>` tag with `charset` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) to decode the document; failing that the `chardet` library is used to make an (educated) guess about what encoding is used. `chardet` uses heuristics and statistics about byte sequences used to provide BeautifulSoup with the most likely codec.

If you have more context and already know the correct codec to use, pass that in with the `from_encoding` argument:

```
with open('D:/page.html', 'rb') as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding=some_explicit_codec)
```

See the [*Encodings* section of the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).